# Alguém sabe um bom programa para criar base de dados em mysql?

Tags: sql

Alguém sabe um bom programa para criar base de dados em mysql e que depois eu consiga enviar para o phpmyadmin?

Comment: Eu ia sugerir o próprio phpMyAdmin...

Comment: Sim é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Esta pergunta é baseada em opiniões, mas lá vai minha sugestão: Mysql workbench. É ótimo, e permite montar os diagramas também.

Comment: Acabei de o descobir agora mesmo, obrigado pela sugestão, vou experimentar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu pessoalmente gosto de usar este:

> [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

*[Copiado do site]
[Traduzido tradutor do google]*

**Projeto**

MySQL Workbench permite que um DBA, desenvolvedor ou arquiteto de dados visualmente design, modelo, gerar e gerenciar bancos de dados. Ele inclui tudo o que um modelador de dados precisa para a criação de modelos ER complexas, para a frente e engenharia reversa, e também oferece recursos essenciais para a realização de tarefas de gestão e documentação de mudanças difíceis que normalmente requerem muito tempo e esforço.

**Desenvolver**

MySQL Workbench oferece ferramentas visuais para criar, executar e otimizar consultas SQL. O Editor de SQL fornece cor destaque de sintaxe, auto-completar, reutilização de trechos de SQL, e histórico de execução de SQL. O Painel de conexões de banco de dados permite que os desenvolvedores para gerenciar facilmente as conexões de banco de dados. O Navegador de Objetos oferece acesso instantâneo a esquema de banco de dados e objetos.

**Administrar**

MySQL Workbench fornece um console visual para administrar facilmente ambientes MySQL e obter uma melhor visibilidade em bases de dados. Os desenvolvedores e DBAs podem usar as ferramentas visuais para configuração de servidores, administração de usuários, realizando backup e recuperação, inspecionando os dados de auditoria, e visualização de saúde banco de dados.

**Novo! Visual Performance Dashboard**

MySQL Workbench fornece um conjunto de ferramentas para melhorar o desempenho de aplicações MySQL. DBAs podem ver rapidamente os indicadores-chave de desempenho usando o Painel de Desempenho. Relatórios de desempenho fornecem fácil identificação e acesso a hotspots IO, declarações alto custo de SQL, e muito mais. Além disso, com um clique, os desenvolvedores podem ver onde a optimizar a sua consulta com o melhor e mais fácil de usar Visual Plano Explain.

**Migração de banco de dados**

MySQL Workbench agora oferece uma solução completa, fácil de usar solução para a migração do Microsoft SQL Server, Sybase ASE, PostreSQL, e outras tabelas de RDBMS, objetos e dados para MySQL. Desenvolvedores e DBAs podem converter rapidamente e facilmente as aplicações existentes para serem executados no MySQL em Windows e outras plataformas. A migração também suporta a migração de versões anteriores do MySQL com os últimos lançamentos.